# How to convert the column type as XML and extract the value on Snowflake?

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an XML column as a varchar type in a table. I would like to convert it to XML column type and extract the value of Transfer.

This is what my each row value would look like.

```
<PropBag>
<Prop Name="Sub" Value="0"/>
<Prop Name="Adjustments 2" Value="0"/>
<Prop Name="Adjustments 3" Value="0"/>
<Prop Name="car" Value="1"/>
<Prop Name="Answers" Value="3"/>
<Prop Name="Transfer" Value="No"/>
<Prop Name="Applied" Value="No"/>
</PropBag>
```

I have tried converting to to_variant type and applied XMLGET function but still no luck.

```
select XMLGET(to_variant (column),'Prop Bag', 0 ), column from table
```

New to snowflake. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select PARSE_XML('<PropBag>
<Prop Name="Sub" Value="0"/>
<Prop Name="Adjustments 2" Value="0"/>
<Prop Name="Adjustments 3" Value="0"/>
<Prop Name="car" Value="1"/>
<Prop Name="Answers" Value="3"/>
<Prop Name="Transfer" Value="No"/>
<Prop Name="Applied" Value="No"/>
</PropBag>') as xml
    ,XMLGET(xml,'PropBag', 0 )
    ,GET(xml, '$') 
    ,GET(xml, '@attrname')
    ,GET(xml, '@')
    ,XMLGET(xml, 'Prop', 0 )
    ;
```

gives

```
XMLGET(XML,'PROPBAG', 0 )
NULL

GET(XML, '$')
[
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "Sub",
    "@Value": 0
  },
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "Adjustments 2",
    "@Value": 0
  },
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "Adjustments 3",
    "@Value": 0
  },
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "car",
    "@Value": 1
  },
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "Answers",
    "@Value": 3
  },
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "Transfer",
    "@Value": "No"
  },
  {
    "$": "",
    "@": "Prop",
    "@Name": "Applied",
    "@Value": "No"
  }
]

GET(XML, '@ATTRNAME')
NULL


GET(XML, '@')
"PropBag"

XMLGET(XML, 'PROP', 0 )
<Prop Name="Sub" Value="0"></Prop>
```

So based on [XMLGET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html) docs, that implies your you don't "need" to access the top level `PropBag` as you already have it. Thus was asking for it does not work, where-as asking for the `Prop` does work..

This can also be seen by the `GET(xml, '$')` which is "extract the content"

in these [examples](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-easily-load-and-query-xml-data-with-snowflake-part-2/) you see it read documents and the FLATTEN on `"$"` which loops on the sub objects.

like:

```
SELECT
    auction_announcement.index as auction_contents_index,
    auction_announcement.value as auction_contents_value
FROM treasury_auction_xml,
LATERAL FLATTEN(to_array(treasury_auction_xml.src_xml:"$" )) xml_doc,
LATERAL FLATTEN(to_array(xml_doc.VALUE:"$" )) auction_announcement;
```